# Employment verification and contract work

Tags: independent-contractor

So I’m recent college graduate and I just received a job offer. During college, I worked as an assistant at a small tax firm. I was a part time employee with set hours for about a year and I worked there seasonally for another year as an independent contractor. On my resume and employment application, I said that I worked there for two years. I planned to mention that I was a seasonal contractor the last year I worked there in the interview but I forgot.

But on the employment application, I did mention that my reason for leaving was that my ”seasonal contract ended.” Also, I have a reference from my former boss (who is also the business owner) who can confirm this. Do I still to need to follow up with my new employer and clarify this?

Comment: Since you've already gotten a job offer I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 4):

Don't overthink it, you're fine.

You worked there for two years, and have been honest about that (even though it was in different capacities it was still two years). Your new employer isn't going to care about the minutia of your employment with a previous company.